# Count specific data in a data frame & display

Tags: r, dataframe

am having exam dataframe  with student.id  marks

```
student.id  marks
     2         2
     2         2
     2        -1
     3        -1
     3        -1  
     3         2
     4         2
     4        -1
     5         2
     5         2
     5         2
```

how could i sum total marks for a specific student.id like below table

```
  student.id     total-marks
       2           
       3
       4
       5
```

how can i obtain the above table with respective total marks ? thanks

Comment: Exactly the same question is asked [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)
Please have a look!

Comment: @m0h3n thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you data.frame is callesd df, this should work:

```
 aggregate(marks~student.id,df,FUN="sum")
```